# Python Script on Apache generates weird "Name not defined" errors

Tags: python-2.7, apache2

I am writing a wsgi-script in Python and I am getting the following errors:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=22229): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/srv/www/wsgi/rtt_by_sig-strength.py'., referer: http://t000.droid.net.in.tum.de/
Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://t000.droid.net.in.tum.de/
  File "/srv/www/wsgi/rtt_by_sig-strength.py", line 67, in application, referer: http://t000.droid.net.in.tum.de/
    allData = measrFilter.getFilteredList(["timestamp", "device_id", "device_name", "rtt"]), referer: http://t000.droid.net.in.tum.de/
  File "/srv/www/wsgi/measrFilter.py", line 23, in getFilteredList, referer: http://t000.droid.net.in.tum.de/
    elif dataPoint == "device_id":, referer: http://t000.droid.net.in.tum.de/
NameError: global name 'getFlatPathNames' is not defined, referer: http://t000.droid.net.in.tum.de/
```

Here is the script (I would like to add line numbering, but don't know how):
edit: Please note that what the script does in detail is actually not important to the problem. It should suffice to just skim it to see whats wrong.

```
import json
import os

PATH = "/srv/www/data/client"
device_names = {}

def avgList(listToAvg):
    result = 0
    for val in listToAvg:
        result = result + val
    return result / len(listToAvg)  

def getFlatPathNames(path):
    flatdir = [os.path.join(root, name)
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path)
                for name in files
                if name.endswith((".dat"))]
    return flatdir

def getDataPoint(jsonDat, dataPoint):
    if dataPoint == "timestamp":
        return jsonDat["result"]["timestamp"]
    elif dataPoint == "device_id":
        return jsonDat["result"]["device_id"]
    elif dataPoint == "device_name":
        device_id = jsonDat["result"]["device_id"]
        if not device_id in device_names:
            device_name = len(device_names)
            device_names[device_id] = device_name
        return device_names[device_id]
    elif dataPoint == "rtt":
        return avgList(jsonDat["result"]["network"]["measr"]["latency"][0]["rtt_ms"])
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unsupported dataPoint")

def getFilteredList(dataPoints):
    returnValue = []
    for path in getFlatPathNames(PATH):
        txt = open(path, "r").read()
        datList = ['{' + x + '}' for x in txt.strip('{}').split('}{')] # TODO: This is a huge timewaster, I think. We should really think of another way of parsing several json data from one file
        for dat in datList:
            item = []
            jsonDat = json.loads(dat)
            try:
                for dataPoint in dataPoints:
                    item.append(getDataPoint(jsonDat, dataPoint))
                returnValue.append(item)
            except (TypeError, ZeroDivisionError):
                continue
    return returnValue
```

I am quite confused by this error for several reasons:

1. line 23 is not in the function "getFilteredList()" as the error states but in "getDataPoint()".
2. nowhere near this line is the function "getFlatPathNames()" called.
3. "getFlatPathNames()" is defined in the same file and above the point where it is called.

Could someone clarify? Thx!